# Negating strings in Ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a way to extract LinkedIn profile pages from lists of URLs using Ruby. Currently I am looping over the URLs and matching them against this regex:

```
/^http:\/\/.+\.linkedin.com\/(pub|in)/
```

However, the URLs of LinkedIn profile directory pages are as follows:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir
```

, so I'm looking to avoid any links that have the pub/dir path in them. I know it's possible to negate character classes in Ruby regexs, such as [^abc] matching any character that isn't abc. Is there a way to do the same with strings? I.e. matching any sequence of characters besides "dir"?

Comment: What format is the list of URLs in? Also: Looks like you forgot to escape the dot in .com

Comment: Thanks, I did forget to escape that dot, but that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead. Something like

```
(pub(?!\/dir)|in)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. Couldn't find anything in Pickaxe's regex chapter on that.

Comment: In the latest pickaxe, "Controlling Backtracking" (under "Advanced Regular Expressions" in Chapter 7 "Regular Expressions" of Part I "Facets of Ruby" has a nice write up.